# As a high school student in India, will I receive an ECR or non-ECR passport?

Tags: passports, indian-citizens, india, ecr

I am a final year B.E student. While applying for passport, I had a doubt, whether I am under ECNR (Emigration check not required) or ECR (emigration check required) category. I have done my schooling in state board.

To clarify the definitions:

> **ECR** = Emigration Check Required
>
> **ECNR** = Emigration Check Not Required

Answer (score 12):

An Indian passport with ECR stamp will be issued only to those persons who are not educated i.e. they have not formally graduated class 10th (in other words have not passed Matriculation examination).

As you are pursuing BE, which clearly implies that you have graduated/passed your 10th grade examination (regardless of CBSE or state board). So you will have to apply for ECNR passport.

Answer (score 5):

As you have not yet graduated, you require ENCR **if you are traveling for purposes of work** to certain countries; as stated plainly on http://boi.gov.in/content/encrecr:

> As per the Emigration Act, 1983, Emigration Check Required (ECR)
>   categories of Indian passport holders, require to obtain "Emigration
>   Clearance" from the office of Protector of Emigrants (POE), Ministry
>   of Overseas Indian Affairs for going to following 18 countries.
>
> United Arab Emirates (UAE), The Kingdom of Saudi Arabia (KSA), Qatar,
>   Oman, Kuwait, Bahrain, Malaysia, Libya, Jordan, Yemen, Sudan, Brunei,
>   Afghanistan, Indonesia, Syria, Lebanon, Thailand, Iraq (emigration
>   banned).
>
> However , the Ministry of Overseas Indian Affairs (Emigration Policy
>   Division) have allowed ECR passport holders traveling abroad for
>   purposes others than employment to leave the country on production of
>   valid passport, valid visa and return ticket at the immigration
>   counters at international airports in India w.e.f. 1st October 2007.

Once you graduate, you are no longer subject to ECR, as listed [here](http://passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/onlineHtml/NonEcrDocuments.html); you will need to provide to matriculation certificate.

Comment: The minimum level of education required for automatic ECNR is 10, and OP already is past that. Final year BE means atleast 10+2, n 3 or 4 more years. Graduation there is not in the sense of Degree Graduation, it is simple school graduation (Class 1 to Class 10, 10 years of education). As you said, matriculation; matric is another name of 10th standard/class